# How Deserialize JSON Api result

Tags: c#, json

I take thi result by Api. I don't realize which class need to cofigurate to dessirialize this.
[image]

```
"{
  \"errors\":{\"Email\": [\"This field should be filled in\"],
            \"Password\": [\"This field should be filled in\"]},
  \"title\":\"One or more validation errors occurred.\",
  \"status\":400,
  \"traceId\":\"8000006c-0002-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb\"
}"
```

i write this classes to deserialize

```
public class Content
{
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
    public string Tutle { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string TraceId { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AppStore.WPF.Services.Helpers.Error]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

it was later and later, accually doesn't mean how write the class correctly

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We're not going to write the code for you, but we will gladly help out when you have an issue.

Comment: I don't understand how write the class in which need deserialize. It's need create 3 classes for main, Email and Password. how use newton i know.

Comment: There's hundreds of tutorials out there, you will learn far more by running through them than asking questions here.

Comment: Thanks for the update to your question, and because of that, you now have your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use:

```
public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }

public class Error
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

to deserialize:

```
\"errors\":{\"Email\": [\"This field should be filled in\"],
        \"Password\": [\"This field should be filled in\"]},
```

Look closely at the JSON (and the error message); `Email` and `Password` require an array of strings.  A hypothetical response from the API might look like:

```
\"errors\":{\"Email\": [\"This field should be filled in\"],
        \"Password\": [\"Password must be at least 8 characters\",
                      \"Password must contain at least one digit\"]
},
```

A first attempt to correct this might be:

```
public class Error
{
    public string[] Email { get; set; }
    public string[] Password { get; set; }
}
```

However it seems likely from the context that `Email` and `Password` refer to input items that are being validated, and that the result could contain other items, e.g. `PhoneNumber`:

```
\"errors\":{\"Email\": [\"This field should be filled in\"],
        \"Password\": [\"This field should be filled in\"],
        \"PhoneNumber\": [\"This field should be filled in\"]
},
```

so that you really want to deserialize it as a dictionary, i.e. replace:

```
public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
```

by:

```
public Dictionary<string, string[]> Errors {get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.NET.
There is plenty of information here:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

You can use a dynamic JObject, or deserialize to a concrete class

Comment: This should be a comment really.

Comment: @DavidG I think this answers the question. If the question were more concrete, the answer would also be more concrete. I'm not going to explain all the possible options, which are clearly explained in the link. it would be rewriting the docs, which makes no sense. However, I respect your opinion.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the question isn't good enough and shouldn't be answered? :)

Comment: @DavidG. Of course, the question can be better, but I don't think it's evil to give a general answer to a general question. Perhaps the Q author doesn't know where to start, and this pointer can give him some ideas. I can be wrong, but sometimes you have to try to understand the ointention of the person making the question. if you think the Q is bad, downvote it. Or ask to close it. Don't blame it on the answer ;)

Comment: Then if the question is a general one, it should be asked as such, but there are hundreds of these questions already. Finding a canonical duplicate would be a greater use of your time.

Comment: @DavidG I challenge you to find that general question. You can find a lot of specific questions on JSON serialization, but I don't think it's that easy to find a general question to mark this as duplicate. It's nothing personal against you ;)

Comment: Indeed, so go create one, we could almost certainly do with a canonical C# JSON Q&A. The problem with this post is that OP has expended zero effort. And yes, your answer is accurate but ultimately not useful.